# how to integrate google map to find current location in swift

Tags: swift

please provide code for integrating google API`s to find current device location in swift programming app.

Comment: Welcome on SO. This isn't a ask-for-code site. Show us your attempts and where you get error/have problems. I'm sure people will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

x-code simulator can't show your current location but this code show your current location when you run your map on iPhone

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let newLocation = locations.last // find your device location
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: newLocation!.coordinate, zoom: 14.0) // show your device location on map
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true // show current location button
    var lat = (newLocation?.coordinate.latitude)! // get current location latitude
    var long = (newLocation?.coordinate.longitude)! //get current location longitude

    }
```